# Node-Red CSV to MQTT

Tags: csv, mqtt, node-red

I am trying to take data from a sensor and republish it so I can use it with other devices. This sensor sends data via LoRa to The Things Network and from there I use their MQTT server to publish the data.  From my flow I subscribe to this sensors topics and put it through a function node to break it apart for storage in InfluxDB.

This is the function node:

```
`msg.payload = {
 Vbat_Per: msg.payload.uplink_message.decoded_payload.vbat_per,
 Vbat: msg.payload.uplink_message.decoded_payload.vbat_mv,
 Fixed: msg.payload.uplink_message.decoded_payload.fixed,
 TemperatureAM: msg.payload.uplink_message.decoded_payload.tempAM,
 HumidityAM: msg.payload.uplink_message.decoded_payload.humidAM,
 TempInside: msg.payload.uplink_message.decoded_payload.tempBMP280,
 Pressure: msg.payload.uplink_message.decoded_payload.pressure,
 }
 return msg;`
```

From here it goes in to an InflxDB node.

If I use a CSV node after the above function node, I can take the data and spit out a CSV string (example: 105,4235,1,6,70.31,5.53,1028.13) but I need to have each variable assigned a Topic so it can be put through a MQTT node. But maybe I could use a second Function node to rename each of the existing variables to different Topics, but I am unclear how to do either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the CSV node? As it is your question isn't really very clear, without a better description of your excepted output format and what the consumers are expecting it will be really hard to answer.

Comment: I use a function node to split out the 16 bytes of data sent from the sensor into separate variables that then go to InfluxDB. I then used a CSV node to spit out the string of CSV data from the that function node.  I know there are many ways to do things, some better than others, but I thought converting a CSV string into individual variables or Topics would be fairly easy so that is why I did not include everything in the flow.  How would you use another CSV node to separate each value and assign it to a Topic so it could then be sent to a MQTT node to be published?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74384418/edit) the question to add details. The CSV node will get you an object with the values labelled with the right keys. If you want to publish each value as a separate message, then I'd use a function node to iterate over the object, but we still don't have enough context to give a proper answer.